# Fisher-Yates algorithm proof

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have an array of numbers $[a_0, \ldots, a_n]$ and want to shuffle it fairly. The Fisher-Yates algorithm proposes the following.

from $i = 0$ to $n$:

$j$ = randomly pick an index in $(0,  i)$,

swap $a_i$ with $a_j$.

The claim is that $P(x_0 = a_0, \ldots, x_n = a_n) = \frac{1}{n!}$. I am looking for a way to prove this rigorously.

Comment: What have you tried? Induction seems like a fair way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof by induction.

Suppose $A_i$ is the set of possible arrangement after the step i.

When $i = 1$, we have two possibles arrangements,
$A_1 = \{(x_0=a_0, x_1=a_1,\dots) ; (x_0=a_1, x_1=a_0,\dots)\}$

for $i = 2$, each of preceding posibilities, alow $3$ times mores, because
$a_2$ can switch with any of the three first variables $x_0, x_1, x_2$

$(x_0=a_0, x_1=a_1, x_2=a_2, \dots) $
$(x_0=a_2, x_1=a_1, x_2=a_0, \dots)$
$(x_0=a_0, x_1=a_2, x_2=a_1, \dots)$

$(x_0=a_1, x_1=a_0, x_2=a_2, \dots)$
$(x_0=a_2, x_1=a_0, x_2=a_0, \dots)$
$(x_0=a_1, x_1=a_2, x_2=a_1, \dots)$

then $|A_i| = 2 \times 3 = 3!$

Suppose when $i = n-1$, we have $|A_{n-1}| = n!$, then
for $i = n$, $a_n$ can switch with any of the $n+1$ first variables $x_0,\dots, x_{n}$, hence we count $$|A_n| = (n+1) \times |A_{n-1}| = (n+1)! $$ possibilities. Hence $P(x_0=a_0,\dots, x_n=a_n) = 1/|A_{n}| = 1 / (n+1)!$